# I can't see any faces of any object at all. Can someone explain why?

Tags: modeling, rendering, faces

I've just started learning blender about an hour ago, so go easy on me.

I'm opening up blender like this:
[image: invisible monkey]

I'm trying to follow a beginner tutorial, but the first thing I notice is that I can't get my monkey to look like the one on the youtube-guy's screen; with faces.

Can anyone explain why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you probably have an AMD graphic card, there's a problem with the latest driver version

Comment: Yuuppp... I'll just wait for a fix then, I guess?

Comment: ot try to come back to the previous version of the driver?

Comment: Maybe, but I've had different issues with an older driver as well. We'll see. If this fix doesn't come within a few weeks I might just revert back.